# Equivalent algebraic fractions with different domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let
$$\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$$
be the quotient of two polynomials. I am looking for $A$ and $B$ such that $\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$ is not defined at $x=-1$ and defined at $x=1$. Moreover, I am looking for an equivalent fraction which is not defined at $x=1$ and defined at $x=-1$.
All what I know is this: $A$ and $B$ are polynomials, if the fraction must be undefined at $x=-1$ then  I need a factor $(x+1)$ in $B$. How do I cancel out this factor in order to have an equivalent fraction defined at $x=-1$?

Comment: "I am looking for $A$ and $B$ such that $\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$ is not defined at $x=-1$ and defined at $x=1$." Well, just take $\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}=\frac{1}{x+1}$. Obviously we cannot "cancel this out" in any way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $\frac{x+1}{x+1}$ and $\frac{x-1}{x-1}$ are equivalent and satisfy conditions. Are there less trivial examples?